How is age(xid) calculated in Postgres? Can it be negative?
I am trying to understand the age function in Postgres and this is the code that I encountered - https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_15_6/src/backend/utils/adt/xid.c#L98
I tried to understand this and these are my understandings -
The age of an a given xid [input param(0)] of the function is
pg_current_xact_id() - xid
However can this not be negative?
x_min for a transaction could be 1000. Post that a transaction wrap around occurred and thus the current transaction id pg_current_xact_id()  is now 100.
So if I want to calculate the age of the transaction whose x_min is 100, I would get age to be negative.
Initially in postgres, during a freeze, x_min used to be set to a default FrozenTransactionId which was 2. However that is no more the case in newer versions of postgres.
Is negative age allowed?
I am not able to test this locally and bring a transaction wrap around

PostgreSQL handles transaction ID wraparound using a 32-bit counter and a process called freezing, marking old transactions to prevent issues. The age function calculates the age by subtracting the given transaction ID from the current one, leveraging 32-bit arithmetic to manage wraparound. This ensures that the result is not negative.
Take a look at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/routine-vacuuming.html#:~:text=22.1.3.%20Preventing%20transaction%20ID%20wraparound%20failures
